# CMD Choice query

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a simple batch file for changing my connection mode to wireless to LAN or vice versa (our company is having trouble sometimes with our internet connection and would advise us to change connections).

Here is the code (I am just a newbie in scripting):

```
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO.
ECHO *********************************************
ECHO Choose Connection Mode (!!!Case Sensitive!!!)
ECHO *********************************************
ECHO.
ECHO [W]ireless Mode On
ECHO [L]ocal Area Connection Mode On
ECHO [E]xit
ECHO.
set choice=
set /p choice=Select Connection Mode:
ECHO.
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='W' goto wireless
if '%choice%'=='L' goto local
if '%choice%'=='E' goto end
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
ECHO.
goto start
:wireless
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" ENABLED
ECHO.
goto end
:local
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" DISABLED
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED
goto end
:end
```

Can someone please explain this line?

```
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
```

I copied and edited a script i found. Just need to know this part for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in question checks to make sure that `choice` isn't a null string, and then extracts the first character of whatever it is, and assigns it back to `choice`. You can find more on substring extraction at [SS64's page on substring syntax in `CMD`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

The entire [SS64 reference site](https://ss64.com) is useful for looking up syntax for [bash](https://ss64.com/bash/), [`CMD`](https://ss64.com/nt/), [PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/), and other scripting languages. I keep it bookmarked...

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You  might want to think about modifying this to use the [`CHOICE`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command, also documented at SS64.